# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list' Error in code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

`int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'` errors pops up on the line of code. I am unable to find a solution.

Am I missing something?

```
L = [[13], [18], [1], [3], [4], [5], [50], [29], [30], [41]]

sum = 10 + int(L[2])
```

I want `sum` to be an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a list of a list which is 2D.
To access an element of the list you need to do something like this

```
L[2][0] # return 1
L[1][0] # return 18
```

To solve your problem try this

```
sum = 10 + int(L[2][0]) # return 11
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you have single elements in your sub-arrays, you can flatten out them into a list without changing further code.

```py
L = [[13], [18], [1], [3], [4], [5], [50], [29], [30], [41]]
L = [i for subarr in L for i in subarr]

sum = 10 + L[2]
print(L, sum)  # => [13, 18, 1, 3, 4, 5, 50, 29, 30, 41] 11
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of arrays, each with one element.
This would probably work:

```
sum= 10 + int(L[2][0])
```

Or maybe you just want to construct the array without each element wrapped in its own array;

```
L = [13, 18, 1, 3, 4, 5, 50, 29, 30, 41]
```

Comment: You also don't need the cast to `int`.